# autoincrement number function-postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, auto-increment

i have a table like this:

| id | person |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | adams |
| 20 | george |
| 40 | jina |
| 46 | rico |
| 80 | naya |
| 90 | john |
| 90 | peter |
| 90 | richard |

i want to find a way to select a new_id starting from 1 and increazing +1 every time id is different. for example i want a select with a result like this:

| new_id | id | person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | adams |
| 1 | 20 | george |
| 2 | 40 | jina |
| 3 | 46 | rico |
| 4 | 80 | naya |
| 5 | 90 | john |
| 5 | 90 | peter |
| 5 | 90 | richard |

is there any function in postgres doing something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use dense_rank()

```
select dense_rank()over(order by id) as newid,id,persion
from table_name
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5eca2a3829bf1a32f31631bd403e716)